# Eclipse Maven: "Cannot be resolved to a type" error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, nlp, opennlp

I am trying to build a simple sentence detector using OpenNLP 1.5.0. I am using Maven Eclipse for that. I downloaded "en-sent.bin" model file from http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/ and placed it inside src/main/resources folder. My pom.xml file is as follows.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>dakshila.research</groupId>
    <artifactId>new1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>new1</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Inside 'src/main/java' folder I have created "dk.research.new1" package and its App.java file contains the following code.

```
package dk.research.new1;

public class App{
    public void SentenceSplitter() {
        SentenceDetector sentenceDetector = null;
        InputStream modelIn = null;

        try {
           modelIn = getClass().getResourceAsStream("en-sent.bin");
           final SentenceModel sentenceModel = new SentenceModel(modelIn);
           modelIn.close();
           sentenceDetector = new SentenceDetectorME(sentenceModel);
        } catch (final IOException ioe) {
               ioe.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (modelIn != null) {
                try {
                    modelIn.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {}
            }
        }
        String sentences[]=(sentenceDetector.sentDetect("I am a student. I am learning programming. I like java language."));
        for(int i=0; i<sentences.length;i++) {
            System.out.println(sentences[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error messages in App.java file.

- SentenceDetector cannot be resolved to a type
- InputStream cannot be resolved to a type
- SentenceModel cannot be resolved to a type
- SentenceDetectorME cannot be resolved to a type
- IOException cannot be resolved to a type

Why am I getting these errors? I tried Project->Clean but I can't get rid of these errors. What do I have to do to get this solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your POM in `<dependencies>` section add:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.opennlp</groupId>
  <artifactId>opennlp-tools</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And then, you have to import classes in Java file before line `public class App` add:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceDetector;
import opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceDetectorME;
import opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceModel;
```

Comment: I did this. (version should be 1.5.0 right?) But i still get these errors. `The import opennlp cannot be resolved, SentenceModel cannot be resolved to a type, SentenceDetectorME cannot be resolved to a type`. How can I fix these errors?

Comment: 1.5.0 shouldn't right because in Maven Repository don't exist: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.opennlp/opennlp-tools try 1.5.3

Comment: Ok. Version should be 1.5.0. The error messages disappeared now. :) Thanks! But when App.java is run the following error message gets printed. `Error: Main method not found in class dk.research.new1.App, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)` How can I solve this?